# Рекурсия в java

Tags: рекурсия, java

Обьясните, пожалуйста, как работает данная рекурсия, к примеру, если х принимает 25:

```
public static int pow(int x) {
            if (x==1) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return pow(x / 2) + 1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Эта функция должна называться `log2`. (Точнее, `log2plus1`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Методу `pow ()` в процессе работы будут передаваться числа `25 -> 12 -> 6 -> 3 -> 1`, пока в качестве аргумента `x` не будет единица, после чего выполнится `return 1;`

Далее будет выполнится строка `return pow(x/2) + 1;` и соответственно возвращаться 
`2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5`, т.е. результатом функции `pow(25)` будет `5`.

Answer (score 1):

Попробую объяснить по своему:

---

При вызове этого метода передается параметр типа [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) со значением 25.

Проверяем равно ли оно единице, и если нет то идем в блок *else*.

Снова вызываем этот же метод но уже передаем значение 25/2 то есть 12

*(маленькое объяснение почему 12 : т.к. мы делим целочисленное значение, результат получается так же целочисленное значение, то есть все что после точки отбрасывается)*

Опять проверяем равно ли значение единице, и снова вызываем наш метод (т.к. 12 не равно 1) уже со значением 6. 
Таким образом мы приходим в вызову нашего метода с параметром 1

```
pow(3/2)+1;
```

И теперь мы попадаем в блок *if* и получаем 1.

Возвращаемся на строчку ***return pow(x / 2) + 1***, получается что вот эта часть кода **pow(x / 2)** нам вернула значение 1, осталось сделать + 1.

Итого: **pow(x / 2) + 1** = 2.

Вот что получается:

```
return pow(25/2) + 1; //второй вызов метода с параметрам 12 
        pow(12/2) + 1; //третий вызов метода с параметрам 6
         pow(6/2) + 1; //четвертый вызов метода с параметрам 3
          pow(3/2) + 1; //пятый вызов метода с параметрам 1
```

Теперь идем в обратном порядке:

Результат 5-го вызова метода равен 2, этот результат мы возвращаем в 4-ый вызов метода и вычисляем уже его результат, получается 3.

Возвращаем результат в 3-ий вызов метода и вычисляем его результат, получается 4.

И на конец возвращаем результат во 2-ой вызов метода, вычисляем его результат и получаем значение 5.

Теперь срабатывает *return*  и возвращается значение 5 (конечный результат) тому кто вызвал этот метод.